# How to clear values in measurelt (Toolpanel>display))

Tags: modeling

I am using helplines to determine the outer angles of the cylinder. I need these angles to align the cubes exactly to the cylindersides. Measurelt puts values on top of each other however, making them unreadable (see image) Is there a way to clear these values (then I can also get rid of the light blue angle font which is hardly readable)? 
And if there is an easier way to align these cubes tot the cylinder I would like to hear that too. I know I can duplicate the sides of the cylinder and make them into cubes with the right angle, but that is not what I want.
[image: Angles with Measurlt]
[image]

Comment: Can you make Snap + face + active + align rotation work for you? You may have to fill some faces temporarily, just to create guide planes. Thereafter, translations in 'Normal' space or in custom orientations should work? Even then, it still looks as if circular arrays should be of use. Beautiful model, BTW

Comment: Not forgetting you can snap the cursor to a surface, align your view to a face, and _create_ objects aligned to view. Not forgetting either that you can create the glass  _from_ the frame, in place, by duplicating some of its edges?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a quicker way to do this particular job is with an array?

- Create your 14-sided cylinder at the origin.
- Create your cube at the origin
- In Edit mode move/scale the *mesh* of your cube to  your desired position with respect to one of the the cylinder's faces (probably down X in your example).. leaving its origin behind.
- Create an empty at the origin
- Assign an Array modifier to the cube with 'Object Offset' and the empty as target
- Rotate the empty in Z, entering '360/14' as the angle
- set the array count to 14

You can then select the empty and the cube array together, and translate them in Z to adjust the vertical position of the cubes. and if you edit the cube, all the arrayed instances of it will be edited too.

If/when you need the cubes to be independent, you can apply the modifier.

Comment: Thx Robin for your extensive reply. But my first image was just setup to test how to do this. I just added a second image with the true problem at hand. Sorry for the confusion As you see I want to fit glass in the window frame that has the same angle as the window (or wall). When I created the building I had no idea what kind of windows I was going to put in later on. So I need to find a way to determine the exact angle for the glas pane.

Comment: @TaaskePrins ahhh, OK. Personally. I still think it's better when modeling to think like a  carpenter .. after a few initial numerical measurements, take all angles and lengths from pieces you already have.